# Insecure HTTP Request With Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular7

I am trying to learn `Angular` with `ASP.NET Core` and had a basic project start-up. Now I run into a very basic issue that I guess, require few modifications. I created a web api project and hosted it in **IIS** - Internal server. So I used the api as follows in `Angular`:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Our First Angular App';
    public values: object[];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
      this.http.get('http://192.168.10.100/api/values').subscribe(result => { //Calling the web api here as jSon
        this.values = result.json() as object[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

The above doesn't get data in the front-end with `Angular`. Instead it threw an exception when debugged with browser's inspect element:

```
http://192.168.10.100/api/values - http request was insecure
```

I can understand, it may require https or some kind of security to be integrated. But for the time being, is there any way that I can make the above code working with http request? I am including the configuration files below if those could be helpful:

**angular.json**:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "OurFirstAngularApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "C:\\Users\\AT\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\OurFirstAngularApp\\OurFirstAngularApp\\node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "C:\\Users\\AT\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\OurFirstAngularApp\\OurFirstAngularApp\\node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "OurFirstAngularApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "OurFirstAngularApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "OurFirstAngularApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OurFirstAngularApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "OurFirstAngularApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "OurFirstAngularApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "OurFirstAngularApp"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**N.B**: The above api is working fine when requested I mean getting `jSon` data perfectly.

**Update 1**: Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, 
    // visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        //});
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: `jSon` data - [Raw jSon Data](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1)

Now I got it. Basically it was making a http call and for security reason, it required https. So I tried with an https service that contains raw `jSon` data. But when I've done the following:

```
public default: object[];

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1/').subscribe(result => {
        this.default = result.json() as object[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Finally in the front-end with `Angular`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of default">
   <td>{{ value.userId }}</td>
   <td>{{ value.title }}</td>
</tr>
```

The above threw an exception when used the browser's inspect element, something like this - **Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Comment: It should work regardless if its `http` or `https`, I see that you tagged `asp.net core` perhaps you have some https configuration on your startup?

Comment: I've updated the post with Startup.cs file @penleychan. See if this is something that I require to configure.

Comment: startup.cs looks simple enough, is both angular and your api running on `http` not mixed content?

Comment: I would guess from the error that the IIS server expects an https request, and you're making an http request, so there's a mismatch there. Have you tried just changing the this.http.get('http://192.168.10.100/api/values call to this.http.get('https://192.168.10.100/api/values?

Comment: @AT-2017 Have you tried setting a breakpoint at line `this.values = result.json() as object[];` inside subscribe callback to check if the api is returning valid data?

Comment: I think it's not the problem, but try adding parenthesis to "result" like this.http.get('http://192.168.10.100/api/values').subscribe((result) => {}. I think you should try with an https server...

Comment: Basically I am calling the api from a server to my local project. I guess, this shouldn't be an issue but even removing http from the api callback doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Updated the post @Stephen R.Smith. Could you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Elvis operator on your display loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of default">
   <td>{{ value?.userId }}</td>
   <td>{{ value?.title }}</td>
</tr>
```

The `?.` after the `item` (in this case, `value`) ensures that Angular won't try to render the data **until** the data shows up, so `value?.userId` will work where `value.userId` will fail as value is undefined when the view is rendered, and Angular has no knowledge of the `.userID` attribute until the fetch completes, by which it's already thrown the error.

Also, when using http and result.json(), you will get a single array of your data objects, so you shouldn't need as object[];  I'd also be inclined to type values as any[], and see if that doesn't work.

```
public values: any[];

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.http.get('http://192.168.10.100/api/values').subscribe(result => { //Calling the web api here as json
    this.values = result.json();
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: Tried it @Stephen R. Smith but getting the same error - **Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.** specifically now for the raw `jSon` data in update 2 of the post.

Comment: After the this.values = result.json(); line, add a console.log("Data: ",this.values); line and check the console in the browser to see what the output is there, then add that to the question so we can review. That needs to be a valid array of objects - the error you're getting is basically telling you NgFor needs an array to iterate over, and it's not getting one.

Comment: Thanks a lot and got it work @Stephen R. Smith, the data returned like this **Data: Object completed: false id: 1 title: "delectus aut autem" userId: 1**. Finally did this in `Angular` - **<tr><td>{{ default.userId }}</td><td>{{ default.title }}</td></tr>** without looping.

Comment: Excellent! Logging out data, especially when you're getting it back from a service, is a great way to troubleshoot issues like this as often the attribute names you're expecting, or the structure of the data is slightly different than what you expect, and if it doesn't match exactly it won't work. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable cross-origin in your serverside code, it will be useful for you try it